# How to update just one of items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I'm using `recyclerView` with `customViews`.

on calling `notifyItemChanged(position)`, its cusses `onDraw(Canvas c)` on **all   items** in the `recyclerView` and not just one item that should update

i tried `Diff Callback` and same results

**How to update just one of items in recyclerviw without calling `onDrow()` on other items ?**

```java
private static class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CustomView view = createNewCustomView();
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // bind the data
        DataModel dataModel = getModelForPosition(position);
        holder.getCustomView().showView(dataModel, position);
    }
    ...
    ...
}

class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CustomViewHolder(CustomView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    CustomView getCustomView() {
        return ((CustomView) itemView);
    }
}
```

customView :

```java
private static class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // i'm drawing in here
        canvas.drawText("Some text", paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onDraw() could be called in many situations, and your case is one of them. If an Item is changed it could be necessary to update their interface (Android can't know if this change could change item's height or not, so...) even for other visible items and that's why onDraw() is called on them.

You need some kind of "cache for your CustomView status": if onDraw() is called, but no any changes are made, nothing expensive needs to be done.

PS: I think onDraw() method is one of the most called, so you need to handle the case when it it called many often even if you're not interested.